# SQL table join on itself but allow "0" value

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, self-join

Okay so i have a simple table "category" on this table categories and subcategories are saved. categories have "parent_id=0", and subcategories have a "parent_id" that equals the row_id of the category.

for example

```
ID  name       parent_id
1   fruit      0
2   apple      1
3   pear       1
4   vegetable  0
5   tomato     4

Fruit
-apple
-pear
vegetable
-tomato
```

In this example 'fruit' and 'vegetable' are categories the rest subcategories, i know on this toppic are already a lot of questions which are answered. But my question is:

how can i join "ID" and "parent_id". currently I am using "xampp" and when i join the values xampp doesn't allow:

```
parent_id = 0;
```

because it is linked with a primary and foreign key to "ID".

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self join with an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN c1.parent_id = 0 THEN c1.name ELSE ' - ' || c1.name END AS name
FROM category c1
LEFT JOIN category c2
    ON c1.parent_id = c2.ID
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(c2.ID, c1.ID),
    c1.ID;
```

Note: The above query might have to be adjusted slightly depending on your actual SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a join.
Use conditional sorting:

```
select 
  concat(case when parent_id <> 0 then '-' else '' end, name) name
from category
order by 
  case when parent_id = 0 then id else parent_id end, 
  parent_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cCNYtcpkaD39aV7U64Kn5m/0)
Results:

```
| name      |
| --------- |
| fruit     |
| -apple    |
| -pear     |
| vegetable |
| -tomato   |
```